# Contextual keyword link highlighting in text

Tags: database, algorithm, search, complexity-theory

I have a database of keywords (around 10,000) and each keyword is associated with a URL. I need now to take a user generated text (3-4 pages), and replace all keywords with corresponding link.

For example text:

*Search StackOverflow for answer before asking*

becomes:

*Search [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for answer before asking*

How would you recommend me to build such an algorithm to avoid complexity? I end up with n*n*log(n), is there a more efficient way? Is there a software or service which can be used for this task?

### How I solved this

Thanks for reply @rici. I was trying to build this for a PHP script initially, so the task had to be performed quickly, while article is being saved, but as it turns out it's not that easy.

Instead I have created a queue processor script, which polls jobs on a regular intervals and will update recently saved articles to have keyword highlighting. It takes a while for those articles to appear, but this process can update multiple articles at a time.

I am using a simpler algorithm, but when performance will become an issue, I'll follow advice to build a trie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest putting the keywords into a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You can match each word of the text with the trie in linear time; as an extra plus, you can do this with a left-to-right one character at a time scan.